# GitLab CI/CD Pipeline - Setting VAULT_NAMESPACE to Root for OIDC

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, gitlab-ci, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

I am implementing single sign-on for HashiCorp Vault (Enterprise) and Azure AD, using OIDC as the auth method and Terraform for my IaC. The entire solution runs off a GitLab CI/CD Pipeline.

The OIDC auth method is required to be enabled in the Vault root namespace. I initially implemented and tested the solution successfully using a dedicated namespace issued by our Vault Admin, with the VAULT_ADDRESS and VAULT_NAMESPACE variables in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` set in the below format:

```
VAULT_ADDRESS = "https://my-company-domain.org/"    
VAULT_NAMESPACE = "/nnn/nnn"
```

To reiterate, the OIDC single sign-on authentication works perfectly with my VAULT_NAMESPACE set as depicted above.

However, to enable me set it to the Root namespace, I have implemented two changes in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which I expected to provide the desired result, but neither has been successful. By that I mean after the GitLab pipeline has successfully provisioned my GitLab project code, at the Vault login prompt (depicted below) no login redirection occurs, as per the expected and previous behaviour.

[image]

The two changes I have tried out are:

1. Commenting out the VAULT_NAMESPACE line entirely, i.e. `# VAULT_NAMESPACE = "/nnn/nnn"`
2. Setting the VAULT_NAMESPACE variable to an empty string, i.e. `VAULT_NAMESPACE = ""`

What could I be doing wrong, or how do I achieve the desired result? Is this a change required in my project code........or perhaps by the Vault Admin?

Meanwhile, a GitLab documentation page on GitLab.com describes the VAULT_NAMESPACE as:

```
VAULT_NAMESPACE - Optional. The Vault Enterprise namespace to use for reading secrets and authentication.
If no namespace is specified, Vault uses the root ("/") namespace.
```

Comment: It is currently unclear what you are asking here. Are you asking how GitlabCI can authenticate in a pipeline against Vault with OIDC and namespaces enabled? Are you asking why setting a namespace disabled OIDC authentication in Vault? Are you asking how to modify the Vault namespace for the OIDC authentication engine when provisioning a server cluster with Terraform in GitlabCI? Please directly state the question.

Comment: @MattSchuchard so let me perhaps summarise the issue as follows - 1) Having the VAULT_NAMESPACE variable set to the "/nnn/nnn" namespace in my .gitlab-ci.yml file, my OIDC solution works as required and I'm able to log into Vault via SSO. 2) As I however wish to mount my OIDC auth method to the Vault Root namespace, I comment out that variable in my .gitlab-ci.yml file and by doing so, I'm no longer able to invoke the SSO redirect when logging into Vault. My question then is - How can I mount/provision the OIDC auth method at the Vault root namespace and ensure I'm still able to login via SSO?